# How to pass variable into javascript template?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, user-interface, frontend

I trying to learn js templates and wrote following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.9.0/lodash.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="helloDiv">init text</div>


<script type="text/template" id="test">
<% hello world %>!
</script>
<script>


$('#helloDiv').html( 
  _.template( $('#test').html().trim(),world : 'EARTH') 
);

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Expected behaviour: I want to see `hello EARTH!`

But I see `init text`

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot wrong here. You should learn to look at your JavaScript console and do some debugging before posting questions, because there is so much wrong that it's difficult to tell what thing is causing your specific error.

1. There is no such thing as a "JavaScript template". That's an *Underscore* template (or, lodash in this case), which is a library and not at all something built into JavaScript.
2. You're using `<% %>` wrong. If you want to interpolate the value of "EARTH" for the "world" variable, you need something along the lines of

   ```
   hello <%= world %>!
   ```

   As it is, with `<% hello world %>`, you're telling the template to invoke a function called `hello` with a variable called `world`. Even if #3 below were fixed, you'd still be getting an error.
3. Finally, and most importantly, you have a very obvious syntax error. You're missing `{}` around your `world: 'EARTH'`. Your script block won't even parse, and there should be a very obvious error on the JavaScript console telling you the exact line on which this syntax error occurs.

Comment: I tired a lot of modifications of template before posting question. console sometimes compains about something and sometimes - not, but it doesn't work anyway. Thanks for you right answer. I didn't know anything about underscore and that it is underscore. I am bad in frontend.